# Post back URL of my C# asp.net WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

Please help me out in my following problem.

Advertisement panel of third party shoots a postback URL with parameters. I want to create a asp.net webservice which can extract the parameters of that Post Back URL and insert it to database.

I can create this perticular webservice BUT THE PROBLEM IS I DON'T KNOW WHAT IS THE URL OF THIS WEBSERVICE SO THAT I CAN ADD THAT URL ON THE THIRD PARTY ADVERTISEMENT FOR POST BACK.

SUMMARY OF QUESTION : I want the Exact URL of my webservice (with parameter), which when fired through the postback, the task written in the webservice will be invoked. 
for example my webservice name is m1y_web.asmx and there are two webmethods named

```
INSERT_DATE(INT COUNT, STRING NAME)
{
// code to insert
}
and GET_DATA()
{
code to extract
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's very difficult to make out exactly what you are asking.  If you have some sample code of what you have tried so far, it might help.

Comment: Why would you use an "ASP.NET Web Service"? ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are wanting the URLs that are needed to invoke the two methods in the WebService.  They would be:

m1y_web.asmx/INSERT_DATE?COUNT=thecount&NAME=thename

and

m1y_web.asmx/GET_DATA

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will use it and will revert you ... as of now thanks for your support